# Auto find files, pass to connection string and read

Tags: c#

Firstly, I would just like to add that I am an absolute beginner at C#, I'm doing my best to learn so I am sorry if this is a noob question, but I have hit a brick wall.

I am working on a program that when finished it will find .DBF files from a specified folder, read the file and insert into a mysql database. I am stuck pretty much at the first hurdle.

I am trying to make the program loop through each file it finds and read them.

I can't seem to be able to access the filename string from the GetFiles() Void.

Is there another way around passing the filename to the queryString rather than specifying it myself?

here is my code -

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data.OleDb;



namespace WindowsApplication4
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        //OPEN PROGRAM
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Waiting for commands...";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Waiting for commands...";
        }

        // FIND FILES BUTTON CLICK
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Looking for files...";
            GetFiles();
        }

        // function to read files at source
        private void GetFiles()
        {
            List<String> Myfiles = new List<string>();
            string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory
            .GetFiles(@"C:\Users\74-des\Desktop\", "*.DBF");

            if (allFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string filename in allFiles)
                    {

                   this.richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,allFiles);
                   string filenameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                    }
                }

                catch (SystemException excpt)
                {
                    this.richTextBox1.Text = excpt.Message;
                }
            }    
        }

        private void ReadData()
        {    
          this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Preparing To Read Data";
          this.Refresh();
          DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\74-des\Desktop\");
          string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=dBase IV";
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + "test4.DBF";

            try
            {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.IsDBNull(1))
                        {
                            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Null";
                        }
                        else
                        {    
                        string DATE = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        string TIME = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        string CODE = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        string item = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();    

                  this.richTextBox1.Text = DATE + TIME + "   " + CODE + " " + item;    
                            this.Refresh();    
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }    

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadData();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this compiling or are you receiving an error. What results do you have, what line is causing it to go bad?

Comment: Yes it's fully working but as you can see, I am reading files in one function and listing files in another, I want to be able to programtically read files, ideally I need them in the same function reading each file it finds

Comment: when you find the files, store them in an array variable globally, then when you click the button 2, don't work with the directory info anymore, just loop on that array and do the reading

Comment: @HadiHassan  Sounds like a logical way! I will look into it, thanks for the idea. Appreciate it

Comment: Side note: `DBF`? It's been ages I don't see one. `CA-Clipper`? :)

Comment: You don't need to loop through the file list in `GetFiles` to show them all in the rich textbox. The `String.Join` will operate on the entire array. Also, you're declaring `filenameWithoutPath` and not using it. If you're using one button to populate the rich textbox and another to read files, that's two separate actions separated by time so you *should* be reading the list twice. Finally, your directory name in `ReadData` is different than the one in `GetList`.

Comment: As @HadiHassan said you can store these files in a global variable and use it but it will be architecturally incorrect. My point is that you seem to jump into the deep water way to soon. I'd suggest you build a few ConsoleApplications before you get into that event-based mess that is WinForms, you should know the programming basics before you start messing with files.

Comment: @EdGibbs Sorry, thought I'd explained this better, I know that they are different functions, I want them to be the same one.

Comment: @userEighty2 check the code below, hope it will help you and if you still have any problem, don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following

```
     using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Data.OleDb;



    namespace WindowsApplication4
    {    
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string mDirectory; // this will hold the directory path you are working on
        private string[] mFiles; // this will hold all files in the selected directory
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //OPEN PROGRAM
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Waiting for commands...";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Waiting for commands...";
        }

        // FIND FILES BUTTON CLICK
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Looking for files...";
            GetFiles();
        }

        // function to read files at source
        private void GetFiles()
        {
            mDirectory = @"C:\Users\74-des\Desktop\"; // better to use OpenFolderDialog to choose the directory
            mFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(mDirectory, "*.DBF");

            if (mFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string filename in mFiles)
                    {

                        this.richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, mFiles);
                        string filenameWithoutPath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
                    }
                }

                catch (SystemException excpt)
                {
                    this.richTextBox1.Text = excpt.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ReadData()
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Preparing To Read Data";
            this.Refresh();
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=dBase IV", mDirectory);

            try
            {
                foreach (var file in mFiles)
                {
                    string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM " + "{0}.DBF", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.IsDBNull(1))
                            {
                                this.richTextBox1.Text = "Null";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string DATE = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                                string TIME = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                                string CODE = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                                string item = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();

                                this.richTextBox1.Text = DATE + TIME + "   " + CODE + " " + item;
                                this.Refresh();
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mDirectory))
                MessageBox.Show("You should Get Files first!");
            else
                ReadData();
        }
    }
}
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I'm getting errors with this part of the code  mFiles= = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\74-des\Desktop\", "*.DBF");   ---- Expecting ; and  = is invalid expression ?

Comment: what is the error? and mFiles=System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(mDirectory,"*.dbf"); if edited the answer

Comment: 7 Errors  -   
Error 1 Invalid expression term '=' 
Error 2 ; expected 
Error 3 The name 'mDirectory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\h42-misadm\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Form1.cs 68 135 HydaExcelSort
Error 4 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @userEighty2 I edited again the answer, actually GetFiles returns array and i defined the mFiles as list at the top, but now i fixed this, I coded without testing

Comment: Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\h42-misadm\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Form1.cs 74 86 HydaExcelSort
Error 6 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'var' to 'string' 
Error 7 The name 'mDirectory' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @userEighty2 copy the current code please, and test it, it should work, make sure the path in the mDirectory is correct

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string)' has some invalid arguments 

Error 3 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'var' to 'string'

Comment: @userEighty2 change *var file in mFiles* to **string file in mFiles** and try

Comment: Nearly working now, but getting "syntax error in from clause"

Comment: @userEighty2 what is the error you are getting, i believe now the problem not anymore in how you read the files, but how to connect right? maybe you should investigate in the line that connection the dbf files